# Azure app service “always on” feature for linux containers

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We are planning to port our app to azure app service linux containers

Questions

1. Is “always on” feature available for linux web app containers ? We have a long running background service.
2. Is application insights oob ?

Thanks -nen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for asking question! I am able to see this feature in linux container web app.

[image]

Check this document on how to configure common settings : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common#configure-general-settings

Further you can also enable Application insights

Let us know if further query on this.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Sneha's Answer-

1. Yes the "Always On" feature is available for Linux web apps but you need to use Azure's **Basic** and **Standard** pricing plan to use that featurere.
2. While Application insights is available it is not available for all runtime configurations. In that case, you may need to enable application insights by [manually instrumenting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/azure-web-apps?tabs=net) the application through code by installing the Application Insights SDK. Please see this [FAQ doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/faq#application-insights) for more detailed information.

For future references, if you see a feature disabled in the Azure portal, it means it's not available on Linux yet. If you want a feature that isn't currently available, please feel free to request the feature in our [Web Apps Feedback forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps). Please make sure to put "[Linux]" in the title so that we'll know it applies to App Service on Linux and Web App for Containers.

Comment: hi, thank you for replying, just want to confirm you meant "Linux WebApp Containers"